# Data not getting saved using JQuery.ajax

Tags: json, jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I want to save data from Textbox on Button click. I am using JQuery AJAX for this task like below. Please note that I made this tags inside theme function.

```
function theme_user_post_block($vars)
{

$themeUserCommentInput ='';

$themeUserCommentInput .= '<textarea id="txt_1"rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>';

$themeUserCommentInput .= '<input type="submit" value="Post Comment" align="center"
class="btnPostComment" id="btn_1" />'
return $themeUserCommentInput;
}
```

This able to show me Textbox and Button inside the page. Now here is my JS code:-

```
(function($) 
{   
Drupal.behaviors.PostComment= { 

 attach: function (context, settings) {
  $('.btnPostComment', context).click(function (event) {
  var post = "&newcomment=Comment1&logid=log1";
  jQuery.ajax({
              url: 'postcomment',
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: post,
              success: function (data) { alert(data); },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(textStatus + 
   errorThrown);}
      });               
     });
    }                    
   }
  })(jQuery);
```

Next I create a Menu Page with URL Name as follows:-

```
 function postcomment_menu(){
 $items=array();
  $items['postcomment']=array(
   'title'=>t(''),
   'type'=> MENU_CALLBACK,       
   'page callback' => 'user_comment_post',        
   'access arguments' => array('access content'),
 );
 return $items; 
}

function user_comment_post(){
 global $user;
 $cid =  db_insert('user_comment')
    ->fields(array(     
    'comment_user_id' => $user->uid,
    'reference_id' => $_POST['logid'],      
    'comment_desc'=>$_POST['newcomment'],
    'createdon'=>REQUEST_TIME, 
    ))
    ->execute();
  if($cid!=0)
  {
     //GetUserComments($i);
     drupal_json_output("success");
  }
}
```

So I have done all things that is required for jQuery+Ajax Submit functionality. When I press "Post Comment" button it gives me error in alert says "errorundefined". The alert shows as a result of error inside the jQuery.AJAX function. Also the custom menu callback is also not getting called.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't look right. Even if from copy-paste, please ensure the code you show is in a valid format as other-wise we don't know if the issue you have is because of it or not. There is for example an additional `'` character in here `'<textarea id="txt_1'"rows="1" cols="50"></textarea>';` in the `textarea`'s `id` property `txt_1'`, messing up the formatting.

Comment: Sorry for my code mistakes.Actually the dynamic value in id is replaced by static value for simplicity here. I have edited the coding portion.

Answer (score 1):

post the data as object...and make sure your post url is correct.. the url doesn't looks correct

```
var post = {newcomment: 'Comment1',logid:'log1'};
```

Comment: I changed the post object as mentioned but it is also not working and showing me error in alert box.Please let me know why post url is not correct and what should be given in actual.I forget to declare $user as global in user_comment_post() here but it is there in the actual code.Please don't treat it as missing.

Comment: url is the path of the page or function that you are calling in the server.... does `postcomment` take you to serverside funtion..

Comment: postcomment is the path of URL. Do you want to say that I need to pass the function name here instead of URL?

Comment: hmm yes ... pass path/to/your/function

Comment: I tried your solution but failed. There must be other thing which will causing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I came to end of this problem. I dont know what might be the resolution or root cause but I end up solving this problem. I meagre add one line(async: false) in my jQuery.ajax function and everything works perfectly. Please see the code below:

jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'postcomment',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          async: false, 
          data: post,
          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + errorThrown);
          }
        });

If anyone have any knowledge as what this line will do then please share with us.